# Calculate cumulate average values using a Google sheet/excel calculated field

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to find a way to aggregate average values in a Google sheet in a pivot table using calculated fields.

Here's my data:

| Close Date | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| March 2020 | £60,000.00 |
| April 2020 | £15,000.00 |
| April 2020 | £90,000.00 |
| April 2020 | £220,000.00 |
| April 2020 | £50,000.00 |
| May 2020 | £100,000.00 |
| May 2020 | £440,000.00 |
| May 2020 | £15,999.00 |
| May 2020 | £85,000.00 |
| May 2020 | £500,000.00 |
| June 2020 | £270,000.00 |
| June 2020 | £210,000.00 |
| July 2020 | £60,000.00 |
| July 2020 | £35,000.00 |
| July 2020 | £75,000.00 |

By using the following calculated field, I can calculated each month's average:

=AVERAGEIFS(B2:B17,A2:A17,">="&Date,A2:A17,"<="&EOMONTH(Date,0))

| Close Date | Average Result |
| --- | --- |
| March 2020 | £60,000.00 |
| April 2020 | £93,750.00 |
| May 2020 | £228,000.00 |
| June 2020 | £240,000.00 |
| July 2020 | £56,666.67 |

However, what I want to do is cumulate the average values like so:

| Close Date | Cumulated Average Result |
| --- | --- |
| March 2020 | £60,000.00 |
| April 2020 | £153,750.00 |
| May 2020 | £381,750.00 |
| June 2020 | £621,750.00 |
| July 2020 | £678,416.67 |

I realise I could add an additional formula column in the sheet itself, but I'd much prefer to do this via a calculated field if possible.

Many Thanks

Comment: how did you calculate May 2020 to be: £381,750.00 ?

Comment: @player0 There seems to be an error in his calculation of the monthly average for that month, so it propagates into the running total.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged both Excel and Sheets, the solution in Excel is to merely select to show the values of the Average column as a Running total (in the Value Field Settings tab).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

cumulative running average:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({UNIQUE(TEXT(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>""), "mmmm e")), MMULT(TRANSPOSE((
 SEQUENCE(   COUNTUNIQUE(TEXT(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>""), "e-m")))<=
 SEQUENCE(1, COUNTUNIQUE(TEXT(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>""), "e-m"))))*
 QUERY({TEXT(A1:A, "e-m"), B1:B}, 
 "select avg(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label avg(Col2)''")), 
 SEQUENCE(   COUNTUNIQUE(TEXT(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>""), "e-m")), 1, 1, 0))})
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @player0. Thanks for your response, the formula is exactly the kind of thing I’m looking for but I am looking to calculate the aggregated average directly into a pivot table via the calculated field. Could this also be amended to calculate the aggregated Min and Max?”

Comment: @AndyEvans surly min and max is also possible without pivot table. here is how you do running total within pivot table: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNyoAi7RerM